# Convex Optimization implementation in C++

Tags: python, c++, optimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I am currently working on converting my Convex Optimisation problem's solution from Python to C++ to enhance its optimization and performance. But I'm facing difficulties in developing a package similar to CVXPY in C++.

For reference, I have included the Python code for the type of optimization problem I am working on.

```
# Combine all constraints
constraints_synthetic = [
    (x + y) @ aaa <= 10,
    (x + y) @ aaa >= -5
]
# Define the objective function
objective_synthetic = cvx.Minimize(y @ eee + x @ fff)
# Create the optimization problem
problem_synthetic = cvx.Problem(objective_synthetic, constraints_synthetic)
# Solve the problem
problem_synthetic.solve(verbose=4)
```

So, I was working on a convex optimization problem in Python, and i used the CVXPY package for the same. But processing or handling a large amount of data in Python was not performance-efficient and was time-consuming.

If there is any documentation or resources that could help me in building it from scratch or if there is an existing C++ library I could use as an alternative for CVXPY or anything helpful, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Asking for libraries recommendation is off-topic. There is also already [similar off-topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791559/how-to-choose-an-integer-linear-programming-solver) with some answers.

Comment: Someone even implemented [simplex in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956950/c-c-implementation-of-simplex-method) and published it on SO.

Comment: [alglib](https://www.alglib.net/linear-programming/) is ok for linear problems.

Comment: How much do you know about 1) the algorithm? 2) Python, 3) C++. You really need to know all three to make a succesfull reimplmentation in C++, one thing that's sure to fail is a one-on-one line-by-line translation of python into C++ (C++ works very differently internally)

Comment: Your question indicates a lot of misunderstandings. Basically all cpu-cycles in your shown code are already c/c++/fortran/assembler without you noticing it.  There might be some DCP-overhead not needed, but skipping it means chosing a solver, understand its api and fill it (sparse algebra). Even if this code spend lots of time in preprocessing/modelling, usually the solving part is even slower. cvxpys third-party solvers are again c, c++, fortran and reimplementing them is expert-work. Summary: it's not easy to gain something (especially in this case), especially without some expertise.